Number of bounded and unbounded components of nonsingular real algebraic curve $y^2 - p(x)$
I would like to know if someone can kindly verify my solution to Problem 22.2 from MIT's online course on geometry and topology in the plane. Let $C = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : f(x,y) = 0\}$ be a nonsingular algebraic curve, where $f(x,y) = y^2 - p(x)$ for some $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[X]$. Since $C$ is nonsingular, it is the disjoint union of "components" of two kinds, namely bounded and unbounded components. The problem requires that we specify for a given degree $d$ of $p(x)$ the possible pairs $(n_b, n_u)$, where $n_b$ and $n_u$ denote the number of bounded and unbounded components of $C$, respectively. My proposed solution is as follows:
Since $C$ is nonsingular and $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial y}|_{(x,0)} = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we must have $p'(x) = -\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}|_{(x,0)} \neq 0$ whenever $x$ is a root of $p(x)$ on the real line (otherwise, $(x,0)$ would be a singular point). This implies that $p(x)$ changes sign at each of its zeros on the real line, and the number of bounded and unbounded components of $C$ can then be determined by the number and ordering of real roots of $p(x)$. Given that every real polynomial of odd degree has a real root, the number of real roots of $p(x)$ must be congruent to $d$ modulo $2$, so let us consider the cases where $d$ is even/odd in turn.
If $d$ is even and $p(x)$ has no real roots, then $C$ is either the empty set (as in the case where $p(x) = -1$) or $C$ has two unbounded components in each of the upper and lower-half planes (as in the case where $p(x) = x^2 + x + 1$). That is, either $(n_b, n_u) = (0,0)$ or $(n_b, n_u) = (0,2)$. If $p(x)$ has $2k$ real roots, $k \geq 1$, let us label them in ascending order as $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{2k}$. Since $2k$ is even and $p(x)$ changes sign at each of its real roots, then either $p(x) < 0$ for both $x < x_1$ and $x > x_{2k}$, in which case $p(x) \geq 0$ and $y = \pm \sqrt{p(x)}$ for $x \in (x_1,x_2) \cup (x_3, x_4) \cup \cdots \cup(x_{2k - 1}, x_{2k})$, giving us $(n_b, n_u) = (k,0)$. Or $p(x) > 0$ for both $x < x_1$ and $x > x_{2k}$, in which case we have two unbounded components on the intervals $(-\infty, x_1)$ and $(x_{2k}, \infty)$ where $p(x) \geq 0$ and $y = \pm \sqrt{p(x)}$, and $k-1$ bounded components for $x \in (x_2,x_3) \cup (x_4, x_5) \cup \cdots \cup(x_{2k - 2}, x_{2k - 1})$ where $p(x) \geq 0$ and $y = \pm \sqrt{p(x)}$, giving us $(n_b, n_u) = (k - 1,2)$.
Alternatively, if $d$ is odd and $p(x)$ has $2k + 1$ real roots, $k \geq 0$, listed in ascending order as $x_1,...,x_{2k + 1}$, then $p(x)$ has opposite signs for $x < x_1$ and $x > x_{2k + 1}$ and we obtain one unbounded component on whichever of the unbounded real intervals $(-\infty, x_1)$ or $(x_{2k+1}, \infty)$ gives us $p(x) > 0$ and $y = \pm \sqrt{p(x)}$. And we obtain $k$ bounded components on the $k$ disjoint bounded intervals - either $(x_1, x_2) \cup (x_3, x_4) \cup \cdots \cup (x_{2k-1}, x_{2k})$ or $(x_2, x_3) \cup (x_4, x_5) \cup \cdots \cup (x_{2k}, x_{2k + 1})$ - where $p(x) \geq 0$ and $y = \pm \sqrt{p(x)}$. That is, when $d$ is odd and $p(x)$ has $2k+1$ real roots, we have $(n_b, n_u) = (k,1)$.
